# SQL query, JOIN another table syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My tables:

**Contents: content_id, publisher_id, title, category, trend**

**Users: id, name, rank**

I am tring to JOIN to **Users** and get **name** and **rank**

My code:

```
$query = $conn->prepare
     ("select * from contents 
     FULL OUTER JOIN users ON contents.publisher_id = users.id 
     WHERE trend =1 order by content_id desc limit 20");
$query->execute(array());

};

$data = array();
while($result= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$data[] = array("content_id"    =>$result['content_id'], 
                "publisher_id"  =>$result['publisher_id'],
                "publisher_name"=>$result['name'],
                "publisher_rank"=>$result['rank],
                "title"         =>$result['title'],
                "category"      =>$result['category'],
                "type"          =>$result['type']
                );

};
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Please give a data set of examples and the exact output you desire from the query.

Comment: The error is, about SQL query Syntax in OUTHER JOIN...

Comment: `WHERE trend =1` where is `trend` field?

Comment: Also mysql not support FULL OUTER JOIN. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: in contents table,  sorry about that

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope this help

```
$query = $conn->prepare("select * from contents JOIN users ON contents.publisher_id = users.id 
     WHERE trend = 1 order by content_id desc limit 20");
$query->execute();

$data = array();
while($result= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$data[] = array("content_id"    =>$result['content_id'], 
                "publisher_id"  =>$result['publisher_id'],
                "publisher_name"=>$result['name'],
                "publisher_rank"=>$result['rank'],
                "title"         =>$result['title'],
                "category"      =>$result['category'],
                "type"          =>$result['type']
                );

};
echo json_encode($data);
```